# MIPS instructions generated for zig `@mulAdd`?

Tags: mips, zig

## System info

- zig version 0.12.0-dev.15+1c7798a3c
- zig flags: -O ReleaseFast -target mips-linux-gnu

## Background

New to MIPS, trying to figure out some simple examples!

I have the following zig code:

```
export fn mul_add(num: f32) f32 {
    const result = 2e-3 * num + 1;
    return result;
}
```

that generates the assembly:

```
$CPI0_0:
        .4byte  0x3b03126f
$CPI0_1:
        .4byte  0x3f800000
mul_add:
        lui     $1, %hi($CPI0_0)
        lwc1    $f0, %lo($CPI0_0)($1)
        lui     $1, %hi($CPI0_1)
        lwc1    $f1, %lo($CPI0_1)($1)
        mul.s   $f0, $f12, $f0           # <- here's the multiply!
        jr      $ra
        add.s   $f0, $f0, $f1            # <- here's the add!
```

If I change that zig code to use the builtin function `@mulAdd`:

```
export fn mul_add(num: f32) f32 {
    const result = @mulAdd(f32, 2e-3, num, 1);
    return result;
}
```

it will instead generate this assembly:

```
$CPI0_0:
        .4byte  0x3b03126f
mul_add:
        addiu   $sp, $sp, -24           # <- ...what is this add doing?
        sw      $ra, 20($sp)
        lui     $1, %hi($CPI0_0)
        lwc1    $f14, %lo($CPI0_0)($1)
        jal     fmaf                    # <- multiply-then-add instruction?
        lui     $6, 16256
        lw      $ra, 20($sp)
        jr      $ra
        addiu   $sp, $sp, 24            # <- ...is this add undoing the first add?
```

[compiler explorer link](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1AAvPMFJL6yAngGVG6AMKpaAVxYM9DgDJ4GmADl3ACNMYhAANlIAB1QFQlsGZzcPPVj4mwFffyCWUPCoy0xrRKECJmICZPdPLgtMK0yGMoqCbMCQsMiLcsrq1LqFXra/DryuiIBKC1RXYmR2DgB6JYBqABUAT2jMVc3Z4lW0LFWEMMxSVZJV2lQmdFXDVcxVVmj6ADoAUg0AQRfYpVVlQGKsWK5aAB9e7oCAMdwgYEAZgATJNkSjVl8AOwAIR%2Bv1WRKOAiGq2ImAUEIIWKRABFVijMABaJGrABUq3hLCxKNxqy4XyR%2BL%2BxPJmAIc1BFKptAIQpFvxxdIJHGmtE4AFZeJ4OFpSKhOAAtMyrBQHBa8pE8UgETRq0gQJDHHD4IhkCjUOiMViLG38QQiMTsKQyQSKFTqPU6EAo/SGExmeqNRL2BhOFw1Lzp9q5fLddIJAT9WoxOJFhi5zoFZPFJotPqZga1koCBsjHLV7pDVolvQ9ypV8YFabmuYLTgrDbbXb7OYkk5nCmXa63e6PUEvN6fAkAkg0kFgiHQ9Cw7mIqio9GXzE4xVitAMMky6m0hkAAXBtF%2Bp%2BoqMuTKspc3KXFwkwKgSYoUpKxDSpS1IQX8yqquqWo6vaBrGqaY7zLsXwoqivB2tGkzTAA1iAmoaPonCSOh0aYRwvAKCA1HEVo0xwLAzqoCw0Teh6lBoHxAkgMYGhcBo1FYAAbngCwAGp4JgADuADyOy6v6dAEGELEQMEGHBH4FSbJwNrGcwxCbGpwTaHW5m8MJbCCGpDC0GZDFYMErjAI4Yi0Cx3C8FgLAJuIXl4BSJQyZSGEvMUri6Y55CCA0GG0HgwTEKZzhYBhBDEHgLCOdMVAGMAChKapGmMClAbCKI4ihg1EZqBhuh1AYRhiUmmXBCxkDTKg0RNEFzJqasABKDSYEwSgAGLzTSzK9MAEpgng0QKMymXwqozLAPCvCoLFxBFVgg0QKOs2tp4EAOH2dQ%2BKMeZdHUhZNE9ZYZIkQ75oMt31sM31FHd7b/e9PS9k2pYDh2YwA6OFohqhHDaqQur6oaHCrKYwCrBoHySR8GirBAuCENc%2BHWpMRH2pxPEifQgkQMJ/Es2JElSaQsnyZg1XqZp9U6XplCGQxlmmSlUvWbZ9nWClzmMAQbkeRh3m%2Bf5tCBSloXhYs%2Br4NFNixUF%2BoJcgSV%2Brwfi6RqDH9Tl1l5YbRFFSVwVlRVVXKULdXBWGjXBhI0itUo7UMbocbdYm5j9Vdw2jYk42TTN9DzZgS1kqtFTrTSLBbTte2uAdR2uCdZ0XXFQ0tk0aYZikpYvZ2w5pOWX2w%2B3v1ZK9XaAymbYg13A91qUwyQ%2BEgzD03/YT33bdgTM47sGiNHo/R2OcHjppEyTZMU261MEWi9MkeRlHUQ7dGYxhOPMaxtoM2jKKbydnBnxx0xnfEdiSEAA%3D%3D%3D)

This version is 9 instructions total, compared to the 7 total instructions of the original version.

## Questions

- where's the multiply instruction in the `@mulAdd` version?
- what's the gist of the second version's assembly? why does it need the additional two instructions compared to the first version?
- **[EDIT]** it seems that `jal` is used to jump to the `fmaf` routine. But I don't see `fmaf` anywhere else in the assembly. Where is that defined? (e.g., is that a MIPS builtin routine?) Do docs exist for that function?

Comment: The `jal fmaf` calls to a helper function to perform the **f**used **m**ultiply-**a**dd **f**loat. This is more accurate than separate multiply and add. [See documentation](https://ziglang.org/download/0.5.0/release-notes.html#mulAdd): "Performs (a * b) + c, except only rounds once, and is thus more accurate."

Comment: On a platform that has fma as a built-in instruction such as modern x64, maybe [the result](https://godbolt.org/z/4MhEP8sWY) is more in line with what you expected

Comment: As an alternative, you might do the arithmetic in 64-bit float before converting to 32 bit.

Comment: @RaymondChen I'm familiar with the zig docs, I'm more interested in MIPS docs. Specifically, what's a "helper function" in the context of assembly code? is there documentation on all the helper functions available in MIPS?

Comment: @ErikEidt *why* might I "do the arithmetic in 64-bit float before converting to 32 bit"? what's the advantage/difference of doing that?

Comment: Some people will use `@mulAdd` for extra precision in rounding over doing separate 32-bit multiply, followed by 32-bit add.  Some hardware can do fused multiply-add directly so we imagine that Zig will use that hardware capability for both extra precision and extra performance (one floating point op instead of two).  But MIPS doesn't offer fused multiply-add in hardware, and so it uses a helper function to obtain that extra rounding precision at the cost of performance

Comment: So, another approach to obtaining that extra rounding precision is to perform the individual operations not in 32-bit float but in 64-bit float, so that before rounding down to 32-bit it will have extra precision.  This approach will avoid the use of the helper function, so could potentially improve performance over calling the helper function.

Comment: "What's a 'helper function' in the context of assembly code?" In general, a "helper function" is a function that helps you do something. In this case, it's a function that the zig compiler writers taught the zig compiler to use when somebody asked it to do a `@mulAdd` on MIPS.

Comment: @ErikEidt ahhh I understand, basically `@mulAdd` gives you extra accuracy, but using float64's would also give you extra accuracy. That's true! However I'm not necessarily trying to get more accuracy in my calculations, I'm really just trying to understand the assembly output for this routine.

Comment: @RaymondChen I appreciate that you're trying to help me understand, but "a helper function is a function that helps you do something" is a tautology, and doesn't provide any further information. I also didn't get much from the rest of your prior comment. I'm going to edit my question with more information, hopefully that will clarify what I'm looking for.

Comment: Sorry. It's a tautology because it's just the definition. It's a function that helps. In this case, it helps the MIPS code generator perform a `@mulAdd` operation. If you don't like that name, you could just call it "a function": "It's a function that performs a fused multiply-add float."

Comment: okay, that more succinct form makes sense. thank you for your knowledge and patience :)

Answer (score 1):

The second version calls [`fmaf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/fma); This is just a C99 function not a builtin. The additional adds you're seeing are for moving the stack pointer `$sp` to pass arguments to `fmaf` (and to reset it again after the call) – I'm not that familiar with MIPS specifically but apparently the calling convention here is to pass *some* arguments via register and *some* via the stack, you'd have to read the docs for the exact details.

Comment: so the assembly code is calling a C99 function? how does that work? is it just another assembly routine that the compiler provides?

Comment: "how does that work?" – I'm not sure what you mean. It works like you see in the code, it writes some arguments in the register, pushes some on the stack (according to the calling convention) and then just jumps to the `fmaf` label using the `jal` instruction.

Comment: No, I mean how is assembly code calling a routine that’s exclusive to a higher level language like C99? I thought every natively-compiled language gets converted into pure assembly.

Comment: also, where is the `fmaf` routine stored? is it some DLL that C99 provides? from the assembly it doesn't look like it's stored anywhere in my program.

Comment: alsoalso, what other "external" routines are available via `jal`? is there a bit of documentation for MIPS that lists them all, or talks about this in any detail? (I haven't seen any so far.)

Comment: @CrepeGoat The `fmaf` function is not part of the MIPS architecture. It's just a function in a library. (In this case, the C runtime library.)

Comment: okay... `fmaf` is not a part of MIPS, it's a part of the C runtime library. is the C runtime library like a dynamically-linked library? is it something that the OS provides?

Comment: @CrepeGoat again, `jal` is just a jump+restore return address instruction. It's like `CALL` in some other assembly languages. I don't know where in your assembly you're looking, but apparently your assembler does know about that label so it's available somehow. It _might_ be dynamically linked, but it doesn't _have_ to be.

Comment: @CrepeGoat it's from compiler-rt. A special library of "runtime" functions that get included into code. clang includes an implementation; so does zig.